# What happens when the Stinger levels up?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I'm using a Stinger in MW3, and I see that it can level up like other weapons. Why do I care? It doesn't seem there are any attachments of any kind.

Comment: By the way, not answering your question but a good thing to do if you want to level up the stinger, is play Drop Zone with it and Blind Eye Pro. Whenever you hear "Enemy Care Package", aim for the chopper. Even if you fire late, the missile will follow the chopper until it gets it down. You'll win a ton of Stinger XP ! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secondary weapons don't have camos, and their max level is 10, not 31 (this is for primary weapons only, with which you in fact get a golden camo when you reach max level).

The only thing you can get with using the stinger is titles.

Answer (score 3):

Edited for the correct answer : The Stinger's max level is 10, and as @rdurand says, you only get titles. (Sorry about the mistake, havent been playing in a long time :P)

The good thing about the Stinger is that it has a faster Lock-On than the Javelin, and usually most air streaks get downed in 1 shot with the Stinger (unless they have flares, or are hugeass copters/planes).

Stingers also have more ammo than Javelins.

Comment: Woah, how's that a 4 times upvoted & accepted answer ?! This is completely wrong.

Comment: This is wrong. Launchers don't get any camo at all. And Level 31 is only for primary weapons. The max. level secondarys reach is level 10.

Comment: I previous accepted this an answer since it was voted and I believed him. Now that I am seeing that this is not the case, I have changed the correct answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake, we're not all perfect :P

Comment: lol, I'm always shocked on SO when I see a wrong answer upvoted multiple times :)

Comment: In multiplayer, Stinger and Javelin both only have one missile.  Only RPG has two, but that doesn't have lock-on.

Answer (score 1):

When the Stinger levels up, it simply levels up and gives you bonus XP, unless you quit in the middle of a match.